# Extracting matched words from a string

Tags: regex, r

I have a database structure - abbreviated version below

```
structure(list(sex1 = c("totalmaleglobal", "totalfemaleglobal", 
"totalglobal", "totalfemaleGSK", "totalfemaleglobal", 
"totalfemaleUN")), .Names = "sex1", row.names = c(NA, 6L),
class="data.frame")
```

I want to extract the words 'total', 'totalmale', 'totalfemale'

How do do this?

I tried regex with the following code

```
pattern1=c("total")
pattern2=c("totalmale")
pattern3=c("totalfemale")

daly$sex <- str_extract(daly$sex1,pattern1)
daly$sex <- str_extract(daly$sex1,pattern2)
daly$sex <- str_extract(daly$sex1,pattern3)
```

But its giving me NA.

Comment: Well, you get `NA` for example where `pattern3` does not match. So one option would be to use `daly$sex[!is.na(daly$sex)]` from the 2nd row on. (E.g. `daly$sex[!is.na(daly$sex)] <- str_extract(daly$sex1!is.na(daly$sex)] ,pattern2)`)

Comment: I think your description is not clear as `total` also matches `totalmale` and `totalfemale` and there is no single instance of `total` alone in the column.  CAn you show the expected output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe

```
library(stringr)
daly$sex <- str_extract(daly$sex1,paste(rev(mget(ls(pattern = "pattern\\d+"))), collapse="|"))
daly
#                sex1         sex
# 1   totalmaleglobal   totalmale
# 2 totalfemaleglobal totalfemale
# 3       totalglobal       total
# 4    totalfemaleGSK totalfemale
# 5 totalfemaleglobal totalfemale
# 6     totalfemaleUN totalfemale
```

Comment: great thanks - why do you reverse the pattern. Is that why it wasnt working?

Comment: pattern3 is longer and includes the pattern 2 as its starting substring.  Same goes for pattern 2 and pattern 1. If you do not reverse them, you won't get the longer alternatives since they are not anchored on both ends.

Answer (score 2):

Two steps with `gsub`,

```
v2 <- gsub(paste(v1, collapse='|'), '', d1$sex1)

gsub(paste(v2, collapse='|'), '', d1$sex1)
#[1] "totalmale"   "totalfemale" "total"       "totalfemale" "totalfemale" "totalfemale"
```

where

```
v1 <- c('total', 'totalmale', 'totalfemale')
```

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
test = structure(list(sex1 = c("totalmaleglobal", "totalfemaleglobal", 
                    "totalglobal", "totalfemaleGSK", "totalfemaleglobal", 
                    "totalfemaleUN")), .Names = "sex1", row.names = c(NA, 6L),
                    class="data.frame")

total = grep("total", test[[1]], perl=TRUE, value=TRUE)
totalmale = grep("totalmale", test[[1]], perl=TRUE, value=TRUE)
totalfemale = grep("totalfemale", test[[1]], perl=TRUE, value=TRUE)

print(total)
print(totalmale)
print(totalfemale)
```

Answer (score 0):

We could also do `sapply` and `grepl` (in base R) over the wanted patterns (`s1` vector) as follows:

```
x <- sapply(s1,function(x) grepl(x, d1$sex1))
colnames(x)[max.col(x, ties.method = "first")]

# [1] "totalmale" "totalfemale" "total" "totalfemale" "totalfemale" "totalfemale"
```

where

```
s1 <- c("totalmale", "totalfemale", "total")
```